# how do i position my nav element under my header element?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want my navigation to be under my 'Acme Web Design' header whenever I view it on a mobile device. All my elements are positioned in the correct place for a laptop screen but when I check if it is responsive, they don't position at the place where I want them to be.

Here is what my header looks like in a responsive view.

[image]

This is the HTML and CSS file i used.

```css
.headerdiv {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: flex-end;
}

/* Header */
header{
    background-color: #35424a;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ff6600;
    color: white;
    padding-top: 30px;
    min-height: 70px;
}
nav {
    float: right;
    margin-bottom: 30px ;
}

nav a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="headerdiv">
            <h1>Acme Web Design</h1>
            <nav>
                <a href="index.html">HOME</a>
                <a href="about.html">ABOUT</a>
                <a href="services.html">SERVICES</a>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

This is what I want my header to look like

[image]

Comment: Simply don't use `display: flex;` if all you need is flex-less layout.

Comment: Can you spare some of your precious time to review the answers and tell us which one worked for you. If you don't you will not receive any answers in the future because people who give answers also see whether or not the person tried the given answers and responded to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is what you were trying to achieve. Here is the working [Codepen Link](https://codepen.io/Wahed98666/pen/QJKRxd)

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.headerdiv {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.headerdiv h1 {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.headerdiv h1 span {
  color: #e7491c;
}


/* Header */

header {
  background-color: #35424a;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ff6600;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 30px;
  min-height: 70px;
}

nav {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

nav a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

nav a.active {
  color: #e7491c;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="headerdiv">
      <h1><span>Acme</span> Web Design</h1>
      <nav>
        <a href="index.html" class="active">HOME</a>
        <a href="about.html">ABOUT</a>
        <a href="services.html">SERVICES</a>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your flex settings for the container as follows (especially `flex-direction: column;`), use `text-align: center` for the child elements of `.headerdiv` to center them and delete the floats to include all elements in the parent element/background

Oh, and put those extra rules in a *media query* to leave your desktop view untouched - the snippet below only shows the mobile view, no media queries (since you didn't have any in your code)

```css
headerdiv {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.headerdiv>* {
  text-align: center;
}

/* Header */

header {
  background-color: #35424a;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ff6600;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 30px;
  min-height: 70px;
}

nav {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

nav a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="headerdiv">
        <h1>Acme Web Design</h1>
        <nav>
          <a href="index.html">HOME</a>
          <a href="about.html">ABOUT</a>
          <a href="services.html">SERVICES</a>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your css property of class `.headerdiv` and remove `nav` class.

```
.headerdiv {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    }

    /* Header */
    header {
    background-color: #35424a;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ff6600;
    color: white;
    padding-top: 30px;
    min-height: 70px;
    }

    nav a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.. you will get same result in any device.

if you want to increase the size of the menu u can do that using font-size..

```css
 headerdiv {
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
align-items: flex-end;
}

/* Header */
header{

background-color: #35424a;
border-bottom: 2px solid #ff6600;
color: white;
padding-top: 8px;
min-height: 70px;

}

nav {

/* float: right; */
text-align: center;
margin-bottom: 30px ;

}

nav a {

color: white;
text-decoration: none;
padding: 10px;

}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
   <div class="headerdiv"> 
    <div>
     <h1 style="text-align: center;">Acme Web Design</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
    <nav>
     <a href="index.html">HOME</a>
     <a href="about.html">ABOUT</a>
     <a href="services.html">SERVICES</a>
    </nav>
   </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</header>
```